# Variable acceleration problem

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, physics, kinematics

So here is the question:
A particle moves in a straight line. When the particle’s displacement from a
fixed origin is $x$ m, its velocity is $v$ m/s and its acceleration is $a$ m/$s^2$. Given that
$a = 2v^3$ and that $v = 2$ when $x = 0$, find the relationship between $x$ and $v$.

Because:

- $a  = 2v^3$

$v \frac{dv}{dx} =  2v^3 $

$\frac{1}{2} v^2 \frac{dv}{dx}$= $\frac{1}{2} v^4$

$\frac{dv}{dx} = v^2$

I am stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a separable ODE:

$$v\frac{dv}{dx}=2v^3\implies v^{-2}dv=2dx\implies -v^{-1}=2x+c,$$

and using the initial condition $v=2$ when $x=0$ implies $c=-1/2$, so

$$v=\frac{2}{1-4x}.$$